# Not getting Ads eturned on integrating Ads for AdMarvel in Android

Tags: android, ads

I am integrating admarvl in the application in which i am requesting for ads to admarvel and getting with following code .

```
adMarvelrequest.requestNewAd(mTargetParams, PARTNER_ID,SITE_ID,mContext);
```

and getting following response

```
 08-12 21:55:53.279: D/admarvel(1132): Error Code: 200
    08-12 21:55:53.279: D/admarvel(1132): Content Length: -1
    08-12 21:55:53.279: D/admarvel(1132): Admarvel XML Response:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
08-12 21:55:53.279: D/admarvel(1132): <ad id="" ip="122.160.65.119" type="error"><errorCode>204</errorCode><errorReason>Bannerid empty, banner must not be configured.</errorReason></ad>
```

I am unable to understand that error please what mistake i have done please help .

Comment: Bannerid empty, banner must not be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
https://wiki.operamediaworks.com/display/AMS/Error+Codes

> 204 
>   NO_BANNER_FOUND
>
> No matching ad is found for this request.
>
> The system displays 204 error when the following conditions are met:
>       * Targeting at banner and that at linked sites do not match.
>       * The weight of the banner linked to the site is zero.
>       * The banner is not linked to any site.

Although I've seen this happening sometimes and working again next day. A success message looks quite similar, except that it contains an actual ad. I would suggest contacting support.

```
08-06 11:05:52.193 D/admarvel: Connection Status Code: 200
08-06 11:05:52.193 D/admarvel: Content Length: -1
08-06 11:05:52.210 D/admarvel: Admarvel XML Response:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                               <ad id="1472157" ip="xxx.yyy.zzz.www" type="javascript" source="campaign"  ave="0"  >...
```